# Presenting TableView with header instead of middle section or footer

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a custom `tableView` with a header and some sections. I am using tabs to between three viewControllers. `ViewController` with `tableView` is my home page of the app. When I first open the app every thing is okay. But if I scroll down my `tableView` and then move to some other `viewController` using tab and come back to my Home screen, `TableView` is presented with the section where I left. I want it to be presented with header(my viewController should be presented from top instead of middle). Here are the screen shots.

**This is my home screen**

[image]

**And If I scroll down like below**

[image]

**And move to next screen using below tabBar**

[image]

**This is what i get when I come back to home screen**

[image]

Should it not be presented same as first time ?

Comment: This is happening because the Tab Bar controller doesn't reload the table view again. You might need to scroll your tableView to top when somebody switches the tab to your home controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first tab's `viewControllers`, add following code inside `viewWillAppear()` method.

```
let scrollPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
self.tableView.setContentOffset(scrollPoint, animated: false)
```

Comment: if you use `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` it might crash if you have not that `indexPath` thats why i give you answer with `setContentOffset`. If your tableView have no data then also it is not going to crash.

Comment: Welcome, Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

What you might have to do is, implement the delegate

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

Now in this delegate when your home view controller is selected, access your table view and scroll it to the op programmatically.